# NtExtendSection() и многопоточность

Tags: windows, windows-10, kernel

Внезапно замечено, что вызов NtExtendSection() в Windows 10 приводит к кратковременной недоступности всей секции в других потоках.

Т.е. если один поток расширяет секцию, то другой в это время может упасть (access violation) на чтении внутри секции в пределах её прежнего размера.

Тоже самое происходит если секцию наращивать неявно через VirtualAlloc() на её конце.

Все это на последней (на данный момент) версии Windows 10 1803 build 17134.407.

Мне нужно понять - баг это или фича?
Все разумные советы приветствуются.

Судя по [доступным в сети](https://github.com/mic101/windows/blob/master/WRK-v1.2/base/ntos/mm/extsect.c) старым исходникам ядра это баг, которого раньше не было, т.е. там не прослеживается какое-либо «от-map-ливание» уже созданных PTE в начале секции.

Вызов NtExtentSection() делается вот в [этом контексте](https://github.com/leo-yuriev/libmdbx/blob/f626acb39822f905dad4ce65d03a27fd05b9fee8/src/osal.c#L1031).
На всякий отмечу, что уменьшение секции выполняется с приостановкой других потоков внутри процесса, чего хотелось-бы избежать в остальных случаях.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow! Мне кажется будет полезно, если вы добавите больше подробностей по воспроизведению описанного поведения (возможно я ошибаюсь и профильному специалисту будет достаточно указанных?), а также укажете более частые метки типа используемого языка программирования, типа C++ или используемой ОС типа windows, чтобы вопрос был заметнее.

Comment: Сам с этим не имел дела, но из общих соображений очевидно, что при **любом** изменении размера блока памяти к нему обращаться не стоит. Даже если его базовый адрес остался прежним, совсем не факт, что он физически не переместился. Ну а если в процессе перемещения идут обращения, то из этого явно ничего хорошего не выйдет. Чисто теоретически, конечно.